# Windows Error Reporting LocalDumps return null when trying to create the registry

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey

I'm trying to read the LocalDumps folder in the registry path but everytime I try to do so I get null if I remove the "LocalDumps" from the path it finds it but not the full path in which I need

```
// Adds keys to "LocalDumps" to registry and adds its value
RegistryKey myKey2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps",true);
if (myKey2 != null)
{
    myKey2.SetValue("DumpCount", "00000100", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    myKey2.SetValue("DumpType", "00000002", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    myKey2.SetValue("HelpUrl", "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181(VS.85).aspx", RegistryValueKind.String);
    myKey2.SetValue("DumpFolder", "%LOCALAPPDATA%\\CrashDumps", RegistryValueKind.ExpandString);
    myKey2.Close();
}
```

Any ideas, on what I'm doing wrong?